# package installation incomplete on lxc fedora 39 container

Tags: containers, fedora, lxc

I want to install a package on a lxc container. One path from the package is missing after successful installation:

path: /usr/share/doc/pdns

```
ll -a /usr/share/doc/pdns/schema.mysql.sql
ls: cannot access '/usr/share/doc/pdns/schema.mysql.sql': No such file or directory
```

In the container I run the install command in debug mode:

```
dnf install pdns-backend-mysql --rpmverbosity=debug
```

I see these suspicious lines:

```
D: pdns-backend-mysql-4.8.3-1.fc39.x86_64: Header SHA1 digest: OK
D:   install: pdns-backend-mysql-4.8.3-1.fc39.x86_64 has 12 files
D: create     040755  1 (   0,   0)     0 /usr/lib/.build-id
D: create     040755  1 (   0,   0)     0 /usr/lib/.build-id/ae
D: create     120777  1 (   0,   0)    46 /usr/lib/.build-id/ae/8ccac2db146485f9d43de496829cc910dce6ec;65a1a39f
D: create     100755  1 (   0,   0)123848 /usr/lib64/pdns/libgmysqlbackend.so;65a1a39f
D: skipnstate 100644  1 (   0,   0)   833 /usr/share/doc/pdns/3.4.0_to_4.1.0_schema.mysql.sql
D: skipnstate 100644  1 (   0,   0)   116 /usr/share/doc/pdns/4.1.0_to_4.2.0_schema.mysql.sql
D: skipnstate 100644  1 (   0,   0)    71 /usr/share/doc/pdns/4.2.0_to_4.3.0_schema.mysql.sql
D: skipnstate 100644  1 (   0,   0)   220 /usr/share/doc/pdns/4.3.0_to_4.7.0_schema.mysql.sql
D: skipnstate 100644  1 (   0,   0)  1583 /usr/share/doc/pdns/dnssec-3.x_to_3.4.0_schema.mysql.sql
D: skipnstate 100644  1 (   0,   0)  1110 /usr/share/doc/pdns/enable-foreign-keys.mysql.sql
D: skipnstate 100644  1 (   0,   0)  2047 /usr/share/doc/pdns/nodnssec-3.x_to_3.4.0_schema.mysql.sql
D: skipnstate 100644  1 (   0,   0)  3139 /usr/share/doc/pdns/schema.mysql.sql
```

*skipnstate* indicates that the directory /usr/share/doc/pdns is being skipped because it is already in the desired state. But it is not.

Installing the same package on another regular fedora 39 host works as expected.